# WordPress back end blank pages after changing the WP_options site URL

Tags: php, wordpress, migration

Okay so, the website was working fine.

The IP I'm using has a VPN firewall on but there's a domain that if used, can bypass the firewall.

When I set the `wp_options` site URL and home to the private IP and I add

```
   define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://privateIP');
   define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://privateIP' );
```

The website opens fine and the backend loads but since the private IP needs a VPN to view it, I can't keep it that way.

When I set the `wp_options` site URL and home to the public domain and I add

```
   define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com');
   define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

The website opens fine on the front end but I get blank pages on the backend without error messages.

All the backend tabs open blank pages and that Is only the case when I use the domain as the base URL.

[image: Blank page preview]

Answer (score 0):

After Change URL please set permalinks. and rewrite your htaccess file. try to add default htacess file and check again

Comment: Yes, I saw that apache isn't taking the updates I'm doing to the.htaccess. so adding: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress will make it work?

Comment: Im changing apache so that it reads the updates im doing on .htaccess, what should I put inside the .htaccess file?

Comment: 1st You can set your permalinks again

Comment: Yes about that, when I switch to anything other than Plain in my permalinks settings, I start getting 404 errors on the frontend page

Comment: define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); Add this code into your config file

Comment: Now I'm getting this: Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50556 Library:50637 in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1531

Comment: define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M' ); add this line into config file and check again

Comment: Note that I get the same error when I set the base URL and home URL to the private IP but the backend pages load there

Comment: I think it's either from .htaccess or I should remove the VPN from the private IP? what can cause this problem other than that?

Comment: You are able to access your backend

Comment: I can access it on both (when the private IP is set and when the domain is set as the base URL and home URL). the problem is that I get blank pages when I set the domain but it's opening fine when I set the private IP